which in turns slows

It works like this: As the glaciers melt and the seas rise, gravity
forces more water toward the equator. This changes the shape of the
Earth ever so slightly, making it fatter around the middle, which in
turns slows the rotation of the planet similarly to the way a ballet
dancer slows her spin by spreading out her arms. (from The Water Will
Come by Jeff Goodell)

Which 'slows the rotation of the planet'? that is, 'which' in bold refers to which?

the whole clause, '(the fact that) This changes the shape of the Earth ever so slightly, making it fatter around the middle'
The pronoun 'This', the subject of 'This changes the ~'

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Are you sure it's not in turn? The movement of water changes the shape of the Earth. Then the change of shape slows the rotation.

@KateBunting It is exactly as written in the original. I didn't change anything.

@KateBunting An over-elaborate interpretation would be that the author was having a little fun, using "in turns" to refer explicitly to the Earth's daily rotation.

The other "s"s nearby in the sentence make it very likely that a superfluous "s" has become attached to "turn"; and a spell-checker wouldn't pick it up.

The prose describes a sequence of causes and effects.

The initial feature of glacier melt is the cause of the effect of
Rising sea level. This becomes the cause of the effect of
more water at the equator, the cause of the effect of
Slower rotation of the planet.

“which” is commonly used to qualify the preceding notion or clause. For example, “The dog, which is his, and the cat, which is mine, both sat on the mat”.

Cambridge
We also use which to introduce a relative clause when it refers to a whole clause or sentence:
She seemed more talkative than usual, which was because she was nervous.

In this prose, which refers unequivocally to the preceding item 3 of the sequence.
The use of “in turn” is an analogy with items in an orderly queue, reminding the reader of the importance of viewing the last effect not only as a consequence of 3, but also as the result of the whole logical sequence.

From a geophysics standpoint, the earth's being fatter around the middle slows its rotation as "a ballet dancer slows her spin by spreading out her arms".
But from a syntactic point of view, in the original sentence there is no nominal expression (a noun or something noun-like) of the fact underlying the italicized chunk above. Rather, the fact is expressed in the original as a participial clause. Here is the original:

This changes the shape of the Earth ever so slightly, making it fatter around the middle, which in turns[sic] slows the rotation of the planet similarly to the way a ballet dancer slows her spin by spreading out her arms.

The participial clause is:

... making it fatter around the middle ...

So there is only a semantic subject of the verb "slows". There is no antecedent nominal form for "which".
I suppose you could argue that as we approach making it fatter around the middle, it is a participial clause but as we leave it behind, it undergoes some sort of grammatical doppler shift, going from  verb-like to noun-like. But I prefer the semantic-subject approach.

The relative 'which' can have an AdjP, VP, or clause as its antecedent, as well as an NP. We could think of this example: 'He is afraid of spiders, which doesn't surprise her at all.' In this, the whole of the preceding clause 'He is afraid of spiders' is an antecedent.

@Mcreaper  I don't disagree. I would consider them "semantic" antecedents.
